# ScriptManager Control preserves history hash

Tags: c#, asp.net, history, scriptmanager

I am using a `ScriptManager` control to load search results from server web services. There is a text box and button on the page where the user enters their search terms. When they submit their search there is a `Response.Redirect` that is called to the search page. I use the ScriptManager's history function to track filtering that the users can do. If you are familiar with this function the URL ends up looking something like this:

```
http://somesite/search.aspx?q=giant+dog#color=red&hair=long
```

My problem is that if the users deices to do another search with the text box and button on the search.aspx page, which causes a response.redirect, the query string changes but the hash history stay a part of the URL. This does not make sense to me because from what I understand of the `Response.Redirect("someURL")` it should act like it is sending you to a new page regardless if it is going to the same page it left.

I know I can set `window.location.hash = "#"` but I was hoping there was a cleaner way than that on the server side.

Please help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but I thought that I would add the solution in case anybody else was looking for this.  I ran into the same problem, where the history point was being maintained across post backs to the server when a `Response.Redirect()` call was made.  I'm not sure why this is happening and it seems counter-intuitive to me.  But I believe the `ScriptManager` is doing something to carry the history point over.

The answer is to put your control that's issuing the `Response.Redirect()` call in an `UpdatePanel`.  So, in my case, I have a button that has an event handler where a redirect is being issued.  Without the `UpdatePanel`, the history point is preserved.  With the `UpdatePanel` wrapping the button, all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `AddHistoryPoint` method of the `ScriptManager`, before `Redirect`.